# how to make a stimulus (image, div, whichever's easiest) show up on right or left half of screen randomly using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how to make a stimulus (image, div, whichever's easiest) show up on right or left half of screen randomly using javascript.

Any ideas about having the button clicks record the reaction time, which button is clicked (left or right), and which side the stimulus was presented on??  Also, the left button should be "true" when stimulus is presented on the right and vice versa.

```
     <head>
     <style >
        .divStyleLeft {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        float: left;
    }

    .divStyleRight {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        float: right;
    }

    .maxWidth {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .button {
            float: right;
        }
    .button2 {

        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body onload="presentStimulus()">

<div class="button">

<button onclick="presentStimulus()">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div class="button2">
<button onclick="presentStimulus()">Click Me </button>
</div>

<div class="maxwidth"></div>
<div id="float" class="divStyleLeft" onclick="recordClick()">
    I AM NOT FLOATING
</div>


    <script>
        let numClicks= 0;
        let timeStart = 0;
        let timeEnd = 0;


        function Trial(trialTime, sidePresented,buttonClicked,) {
            this.trialTime = trialTime;
            this.sidePresented= sidePresented;
            this.buttonClicked= buttonClicked;
        }
        let allTrials = [];
        for(x = 0; x < 12; x++)
            allTrials.push(new Trial(0,0,0));

        Trial.prototype.toString=function(){
            return this.trialTime + "ms, Side : " + this.sidePresented     + ", Reaction Time: " + this.buttonClicked
                + "<br>";
        };

        function presentStimulus() {
            const elem = document.querySelector ( '#float' );
            const min = 1;
            const max = 2;
            const v = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) +    min;
            console.log ( 'Random num is ' + v + ": ", '1 will go left,    2 will go right' );
            v === 1 ?
                ( () => {
                    elem.classList = [ 'divStyleLeft' ];
                    elem.innerText = 'Hello!';
                } ) () :
                ( () =>{
                    elem.classList = [ 'divStyleRight' ];
                    elem.innerText = 'Hi!';
                } ) ();
        }

        function recordClick()
        {
            let theData = document.getElementById("#float").data;
            timeEnd = Date.now();
            allTrials[numClicks].trialTime = timeEnd - timeStart;
            allTrials[numClicks].sidePresented = theData.sidePresented;
            allTrials[numClicks].buttonClicked = theData.buttonClicked;

            if (numClicks < 11) {
                numClicks++;
                presentStimulus();
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("float").style.visibility =     "hidden";
                let output = "";
                for (x = 0; x < allTrials.length; x++)
                    output = output + "<b>:" + (x + 1) + "</b>:" +     allTrials[x].toString();
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = output;
            }

        }


    </script>

<p id="display"></p>


</body>
```

Comment: what did you done so far ? Include your code.

Answer (score -1):

There's a bunch of ways you could go about this.

If you're using plain 'ol JS, I'd probably create classes in CSS that float left or right, possibly appear as a flex container that displays left or right, whatever your specific need might be (again, there's a lot of ways to go about it, and one might be better than the other given your context).

When you've determined left or right (gen a random number or whatever), update the classlist on the DOM elements with the desired class to make it go this way or that.

For what it's worth, here's a bare-bones vanilla JS example. Again, I don't know your specific context, but this should give you a start on how to look at it. Floating may not be ideal, you may want to just hide/show containers that already exist on the left or right or actually create whole new DIVs and insert them into known "holder" containers (usually just empty divs), but the idea is the same; gen the random number, alter the classlists of the elements you want to hide/show/move/whatever, and if necessary, alter the innerHTML or text as needed.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.divStyleLeft {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    float: left;
}

.divStyleRight {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    float: right;
}

.maxWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="onClick()">Click Me</button>

<div class="maxwidth">
<div id="floater" class="divStyleLeft">
I AM NOT FLOATING
</div>
<div>

<script>

function onClick () {
    const elem = document.querySelector ( '#floater' );
    const min = 1;
    const max = 2;
    const v = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    console.log ( 'Random num is ' + v + ": ", '1 will go left, 2 will go right' );
    v === 1 ?
    ( () => { 
        elem.classList = [ 'divStyleLeft' ]; 
        elem.innerText = 'I am floating LEFT';
    } ) () : 
    ( () =>{ 
        elem.classList = [ 'divStyleRight' ]; 
        elem.innerText = 'I am floating RIGHT';
    } ) ();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now I am struggling to have  the button clicks record the reaction time, which button is clicked (left or right), and which side the stimulus was presented on?? Also, the left button should be "true" when stimulus is presented on the right and vice versa.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. If I can offer some guidance as to participation on SO, it seems they're doing a lot to soften people up a bit, but in general, if your original question was answered, mark the answer accepted and if necessary, open another one. But...don't just try to use SO question to get people to write your program. You'll find people can get VERY impatient and even downright rude if you do (which I never understood...why not send a helpful PM or just ignore the question). And always try to show what you've already tried and where you've already looked.